# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer vs ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: spring-3, properties-file

Searching Google on how to configure property file in Spring 3 and I got many different answers. I found that `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` can be used for getting properties from property files. Can somebody please explain the difference between these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

We use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` when we need to load some property files whose properties are used in applicationcontext.xml of spring. We can use the properties directly using JSTL expressions.

#### ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

We use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` when we need to use the property files outside the applicationcontext.xml. The properties loaded using ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource are not accessible in applicationcontext.xml

Answer (score 1):

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer used for properties files to be used in the application context or inside the code with with @value.

ResourceBundleMessageSource used for Internationalization & Localization (i18n) of messages you want to show to the user, within jsp direct, or from your code by wiring message resources bean inside your component.