# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and ResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Can somebody explain to me the difference between PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and ResourceBundleMessageSource ? When to use the first one and when to use the latter one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer vs reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759737/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-vs-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource)

Answer (score 1):

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer used for properties files to be used in the application context or inside the code with with @value.

ResourceBundleMessageSource used for Internationalization & Localization (i18n) of messages you want to show to the user, within jsp direct, or from your code by wiring message resources bean inside your component.

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759737/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-vs-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource)

> PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
>
> > We use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer when we need to load some
> >     propertyfiles wose properties are used in applicationcontext.xml of
> >     spring. We can use the properties directly using JSTL expressions.
> >     reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource
> >
> > We use reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource when we need to use the
> >     property files outside the applicationcontext.xml. The properties
> >     loaded using reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource are not accessible
> >     in applicationcontext.xml

Comment: @Downvoter Please add some comment so that its useful for future readers

Comment: Probably (s)he voted in this way because that post talks about `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and this one about `ResourceBundleMessageSource`.